# Python - Merge two Pandas dataframes into one and update the row if the index exists and add a row if it doesn't

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to take multiple similar dataframes and combine them to form a single frame with all the data. Each frame has a 'Name' and an 'In_Frame_#' column with a true or false value.

I would like to combine all frames into a single frame that has all the names, with no duplicates, and many columns labeled as 'In_Frame_#' with the corresponding True/False or blank value.

When adding to the "full" dataframe, If the name exists then update that row to include the value for the new column derived from the incoming frame and if the name doesn't exist then add the name and include the value for the new column derived from the incoming frame.

I have been playing with update(), merge() and join() functions but haven't cracked the solution. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

The tables below may help visualize my current situation.

Frame one looks like:

| Name | In_Frame_1 |
| --- | --- |
| Rick | True |
| Morty | True |
| Jerry | True |

Frame two looks like:

| Name | In_Frame_2 |
| --- | --- |
| Beth | True |
| Summer | True |
| Jerry | True |

The desired output would look like:

| Name | In_Frame_1 | In_Frame_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Rick | True | {blank} |
| Morty | True | {blank} |
| Jerry | True | True |
| Beth | False | True |
| Summer | False | True |

Comment: Why `Beth` in column In_Frame_1 is `False` and `Rick` in column In_Fame_2 is `{blank}`? Why not both `{blank}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to 'outer' merge the 2 dataframes and fill `NaN` (non-matching entries) with `False`, as follows:

```
df1.merge(df2, how='outer').fillna(False)
```

Result:

```
     Name  In_Frame_1  In_Frame_2
0    Rick        True       False
1   Morty        True       False
2   Jerry        True        True
3    Beth       False        True
4  Summer       False        True
```

If you want to fill `NaN` (non-matching entries) with blank instead, you can use:

```
df1.merge(df2, how='outer').fillna('')
```

Result:

```
     Name In_Frame_1 In_Frame_2
0    Rick       True           
1   Morty       True           
2   Jerry       True       True
3    Beth                  True
4  Summer                  True
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df1.set_index('Name').combine_first(df2.set_index('Name')).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
     Name In_Frame_1 In_Frame_2
0    Beth        NaN       True
1   Jerry       True       True
2   Morty       True        NaN
3    Rick       True        NaN
4  Summer        NaN       True
```